# how ignore property for serialization to JSON in Angular 7

Tags: json, angular

I have a navigation property in a hierarchical model structure that causes an circular dependency error in angular 7 during serialization.

```
export class MyClass {
   // this property should be ignored for JSON serialization
   parent: MyClass;

   childList: MyClass[];
}
```

I wonder if there is any build-in solution (ex. a decorator like this exists for Jackson: @JsonBackReference) to ignore the parent property at serialization (ex. during http.put).

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you prefer to handle this with a decorator you can make your own like this one

```
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey) || {};
        if (descriptor.enumerable != value) {
            descriptor.enumerable = value;
            Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, descriptor)
        }
    };
}
```

and then mark property as not enumerable like this

```
class MyClass {
   @enumerable(false)
   parent: MyClass;
}
```

other option is to redefine toJSON behavior

```
MyClass {
...
public toJSON() {
 const {parent, ...otherProps} = this;
 return otherProps;
}
```